# Fatal Error on fresh Laravel 10.3.3 install

Tags: php, laravel

Normally I continue to research and find out how I am getting errors in whatever it is that I am doing. However, I am completely stumped on how to figure this out. I have recently just started trying Laravel on my home server and went through all the steps to get to installing it. Once I open up my browser to `public/index.php` I am faced with an error:

```
Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 218107904 bytes)
```

The error points to line 51 of the index.php file as follows:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
```

As far as I know everything was done correctly on the install for my end but I can't seem to figure out what is actually causing this issue. Any help is appreciated, cheers!

I have tried reinstalling composer and installing other Laravel versions but still receiving the same error.

Comment: `$kernel->handle` is the part that sends the request via the middleware to the route handler. That means the issue is in the route you are trying to hit or the middleware it uses.

Comment: That's the problem, this is the default index file. So this is the code:

$response = $kernel->handle(

    $request = Request::capture()

)->send();


$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

Comment: It seems php is the issue, so try to increase memory limit ```memory_limit = 2048M```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel dumb. What can I say, I'm learning! But if anybody else runs into this problem the answer is really simple. You must change ownership of your storage folder to www-data. if using Shell:

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/your-project-name/storage

Comment: Nice you did not update your php.ini like the old previous answers (pre 202x). (doing 64mb, 128mb, etc).